# Play 2.3 play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[]

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework

When doing `sbt run` everything works fine. But if I do `sbt start` I get this very much useless error:

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$error(DB.scala:271) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$3.apply(DB.scala:437) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$3.apply(DB.scala:437) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
```

The configuration looks like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"
db.default.user=username
db.default.password=password
db.default.host=localhost
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you correctly add the Postgres JDBC driver dependency in the build.sbt file ?

Comment: I believe so. The build file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/nVJJww34

Comment: it's like if Play were not able to find or connect to the datasource. Is the Postgres server running. I have tried to reproduce your configuration locally and it works fine. Though, if I explicitly shut my local DB server down then I do not have the same error as yours.

Comment: The server is there, though. As I said everything works perfectly fine with `play run`. The database is found and used. Just not with `play start` unfortunately.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a test? E.g., `running(fakeApplication(), () -> {});`